# Using the command line in order to change hosts/hostnames on Centos

Tags: centos, hosts-file, hostname

I need to use the command line in order to **add a new host resolution** on a temporary basis. I use centos.

I need a new `localhost` resolution such as the following:

```
127.0.0.1       something.localhost
```

I this possible with Centos? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `HOSTALIASES` env variable does the trick:

```
echo 'something.localhost localhost' >> ~/.hosts
export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts
```